# Symfony multiple entity managers with one repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entitymanager

I have a symfony/api-platform application which connects to 2 different databases configured in *doctrine.yaml*. I want to notice that both databases store the same entities (but with different actions on each), hence we duplicated all the entity classes and created a repository for each, in order for migrations and api-platform actions to work. Since those enities share a lot of common repository functionallity, what I have done so far to remove code
duplication is:

Create entity manager decorators

```php
class AEntityManager extends EntityManagerDecorator{}
class BEntityManager extends EntityManagerDecorator{}
```

*config/services.yaml*

```yaml
App\EntityManager\AEntityManager:
        decorates: doctrine.orm.a_entity_manager
App\EntityManager\BEntityManager:
        decorates: doctrine.orm.b_entity_manager
App\Repository\Main\AResourceRepository:
        arguments:
            - '@App\EntityManager\AEntityManager'
App\Repository\ProductPending\BResourceRepository:
        arguments:
            - '@App\EntityManager\BEntityManager'
```

Create a base class (for each entity) to share code between the 2 repositories

```php
class RepositoryBase extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
  public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, string $class) {...}

  // common methods
}

class ARepository extends RepositoryBase
{
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        parent::__construct($em, A::class);
    }
}

class BRepository extends RepositoryBase
{
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        parent::__construct($em, B::class);
    }
}
```

And entities

```php
/**
@Orm\Entity(repositoryClass=ARepository::class)
*/
class A {
   string $prop;
}

/**
@Orm\Entity(repositoryClass=BRepository::class)
*/
class B {
   string $prop;
}
```

**Note** that all actions for the second database occur in endpoints prefixed with (let's say) /api/b/...

I would like to know if there is a way to eliminate the different repository classes and define the same repository across the 2 different entities. What I have in mind is to change the object which is used to inject the EntityManagerInterface constructor parameter based on the url of the request, but I haven't found something specific about it and I don't know if that's even possible.

Comment: Does your RepositoryBase extend either EntityRepository or ServiceEntityRepository or is it really standalone as your posted code suggests?  The reason I ask is that Symfony's out of the box support for multiple entity managers that share the same entity classes is basically broken.  It's a long sad story with no easy workaround.  I would say your approach of basically duplicating everything is the best one.

Comment: Yeah it actually extends `ServiceEntityRepository`. Could you point out any resources about using multiple entity managers with the same entity? I can't find something relevant neither in docs or the web.

Comment: Most of the discussion is a few years old.  Basically the ServiceEntityRepository does not support having the same entity class mapped to multiple entity managers.  Two basic issues.  The first is that the ServiceEntityRepository constructor recieves a registry of all entity managers and then picks the first one that has the entity class mapped.

Comment: The second issue is far more subtle.  Doctrine uses a RepositoryFactory to create repositories.  The DoctrineBundle uses a container aware RepositoryFactory which looks for a service which matches the repository class.  This basically means you can only have one repository instance at any given time even with two entity managers.  So $em2->getRepository() ends up returning a repository for $em1.  Fun stuff.  So again the best way to solve this is use different classes.