# Symfony multiple dbs that are the same and use same Entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I need to use two db they have the same content, tables etc.. One db is read only and the other read and write. I want to work with the two of them wheather I'm writting or reading on my controller. If i'm working with only one db i don't get any errors but when I configure my doctrine to work with the two of them gives an error when writing db is in use:

```
Multiple non-persisted new entities were found through the given association graph:

* A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\SsCampaign#ssSponsor' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: App\Entity\SsSponsor@000000004aa20cbb0000000022232781. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'App\Entity\SsSponsor#__toString()' to get a clue.
* A new entity was found through the relationship 'App\Entity\SsCampaign#momentProject' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: App\Entity\SsMomentsProjects@000000004aa20cef0000000022232781. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'App\Entity\SsMomentsProjects#__toString()' to get a clue.
```

I did what it says about the entity and then gave this error: Notice:

`Undefined index: 0000000050839a4a000000005f281a3d`

Dcotrine file

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                mapping_types:
                    enum: string
                wrapper_class: App\Doctrine\DynamicConnection
            writter:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(DATABASE_URL_WRITTER)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                mapping_types:
                    enum: string
                wrapper_class: App\Doctrine\DynamicConnection
            
        #url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '13'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        # mappings:
        #     App:
        #         is_bundle: false
        #         type: annotation
        #         dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
        #         prefix: 'App\Entity'
        #         alias: App
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: App

            writter:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                connection: writter
                mappings:
                    Writter:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: Writter
```

Comment: This might be of use from the docs, working with [multiple databases](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html).

Answer (score 0):

I was missing this part of documentation

One entity can be managed by more than one entity manager. This however results in unexpected behavior when extending from ServiceEntityRepository in your custom repository. The ServiceEntityRepository always uses the configured entity manager for that entity.

In order to fix this situation, extend EntityRepository instead and no longer rely on autowiring:

```
// src/Repository/CustomerRepository.php
namespace App\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CustomerRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Be very very very careful with this approach.  Using EntityRepository only solves part of the problem.  The DoctrineBundle adds a container aware RepositoryFactory which means that at any given time only one repository instance for a given entity exists.  Which means that doing things like $writterEntityManager->getRepository will return a repository linked to $defaultEntityManager.  More discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71479313/symfony-multiple-entity-managers-with-one-repository).